# Code page using git-svn

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

When i am cloning repository using git svn i get something like "єС‚СѓР°Р»СЊРЅРѕРµ" instead of national characters (russian) in file names .... (i cant read this...) I think git is trying to use UTF-8 instead of UTF-16 while saving files, while windows is using UTF-16. Is there any solution? Can i specify code page to git svn?

Answer (score 3):

This has been documented in [msysgit issue 159](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=159) (considered duplicate of [issue 80](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=80)), and debated in a patch proposal "[Windows: Assume all file names to be UTF-8 encoded.](http://lists-archives.org/git/684321-windows-assume-all-file-names-to-be-utf-8-encoded.html)".

I don't think however, that translated in any actual solution.

> The biggest obstacle will be that git does not have a notion of "file name encoding" - it simply treats a file name as a stream of bytes. There is no place to write an encoding. If the byte streams are regarded as having an encoding, then you can have ambiguities, mixed encodings, or invalid characters. You would have to deal with this in some way.

The only solution I hear of is this [msysgit version](http://tmurakam.org/git/) from this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tmurakam/4msysgit-utf8-filepath): you could try it and see if, just for this import, it works better: [Git-1.7.0.2-utf8-20100725.exe](http://tmurakam.org/git/Git-1.7.0.2-utf8-20100725.exe).

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved my problem (invalid characteres after svn dcommit), setting i18n coding:

In my case, codepage is ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8:

`git config --global i18n.commitencoding ISO-8859-1`